# Using nested dictionaries and populate them with a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, caching

The data model is like this:

```
    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public  int GameId { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }

    public class Game
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Type
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
       //and many other things
    }
```

What I want is to have order of every user in every game which shows the rank of user in that game.

I want to cache the data for this which will update every day, what I have done so far is this:

```
class Class1
{
    private readonly IDictionary<int, IDictionary<int, IDictionary<string, int>>> _scoreDictionary =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<int, IDictionary<int, IDictionary<string, int>>>();
    private readonly object _scoreDictionaryLock = new object();

    private void InitializeDctionary(int typeId, IList<Game> gameInformations, IList<UserInfo> userInformations)
    {
        if (!_scoreDictionary.ContainsKey(typeId))
        {
            lock (_scoreDictionaryLock)
            {
                foreach (var gameInformation in gameInformations )
                {
                     var orderdUsers = userInformations.Where(s => s.GameId ==gameInformation.Id ).OrderByDescending(s => s.Score).Select((value, index) => new
                {
                    value,
                    index//this is the user rank

                }).Select(p => new
                {
                    p.value.UserName,
                    p.index
                }).Select(p=>new KeyValuePair<string,int>(p.UserName,p.index));
                }

        // I don't know what to do I want a dictionary that in first level key be typeId and then gameId then userName the final value is user rank.
                    _scoreDictionary.Add(typeId,??????????? );
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An untested code, but should work for you.

```
private void InitializeDctionary(int typeId, IList < Game > gameInformations, IList < UserInfo > userInformations) 
{
    if (!_scoreDictionary.ContainsKey(typeId)) 
    {
        lock(_scoreDictionaryLock) 
        {

            if (!_scoreDictionary.ContainsKey(typeId)) 
            {
                _scoreDictionary.Add(typeId, new Dictionary < int, Dictionary < string, int >> ));
            }

            foreach(var gameInformation in gameInformations) 
            {
                var orderdUsers = userInformations.Where(s => s.GameId == gameInformation.Id)
                    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Score)
                    .Select((value, index) =>
                        new { value, index //this is the user rank
                        })
                    .Select(p =>new {p.value.UserName,p.index})
                    .Select(p => new KeyValuePair < string, int > (p.UserName, p.index));

                if (!_scoreDictionary[typeId].ContainsKey(gameInformation.Id))
                    _scoreDictionary[typeId].Add(gameInformation.Id, new Dictionary < string, int > ());

                _scoreDictionary[typeId][gameInformation.Id] = orderdUsers.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```